# Mongoose populate array and return all documents (even if populate wasn't found)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, mongoose-populate

Just like the title suggests, is there a way to populate an array using mongoose and return the populated documents, along side the array items that failed to find an associated document.

Example, I have the following Model and example document. The document in question has two users (stored in array). One of the emails, is associated with a user in the database and the other is not. If I run virtual populate on this array, I am only given the one user document where the reference was found.

**Here is my Model**

```
const organizationSchema = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    users: [String],
}, { timestamps: { createdAt: 'created_at' } });

organizationSchema.virtual('users_populated',{
    ref: 'users',
    localField: 'users',
    foreignField: 'email'
});
```

**Example Document**

{

> name: "Test Organization", users:["email1@gmail.com",
> "email2@gmail.com"]

}

**What i'm looking to do**

If one of the user's doesn't exist, I would like it to return this:
`[{_id: 109753097121092, name: 'steve', email: 'email1@gmail.com'}, "email2@gmail.com"]`
Or even: 
`[{_id: 109753097121092, name: 'steve', email: 'email1@gmail.com'}, {email: "email2@gmail.com"}]`

What i'm getting (notice the entry that failed to populate is missing: 
`[{_id: 109753097121092, name: 'steve', email: 'email1@gmail.com'}]`

Comment: Can you include what exactly are you running and maybe clean and the post a bit, please?

Comment: @Minsky Added schema and example document.